# how dangerous is it to refreeze meat that has been thawed

Tags: food-safety

I thawed steaks in the frige and added soy sauce to marinade them..they were in the frige for 2 days..I didn't use the steaks and so I refroze them.  Is it okay to thaw them and serve them?